# When I use ' ; 'instead of ' && ', the output changes and I need help understanding it

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, json

When I replace the '&&' between the push methods in the if statement with ';', the output is different. Please help me so that I can understand the weird output when using the semicolon.

```js
var tipcalculator = {
  bills: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
  tipmethod: function() {
    this.arraytip1 = [];
    this.arraytipbills = [];
    for (var i = this.bills.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      billsarr = this.bills[i];
      if (billsarr > 200)
        this.arraytip1.push((billsarr * 10 / 100)) && this.arraytipbills.push(((billsarr * (10 / 100)) + billsarr));
      if (billsarr >= 50 && billsarr <= 200)
        this.arraytip1.push((billsarr * 15 / 100)) && this.arraytipbills.push(((billsarr * 15 / 100) + billsarr));
      if (billsarr < 50)
        this.arraytip1.push((billsarr * 20 / 100)) && this.arraytipbills.push(((billsarr * (20 / 100)) + billsarr));
    }
  }
}

tipcalculator.tipmethod()
console.log(tipcalculator.arraytip1)
console.log(tipcalculator.arraytipbills)
```

Comment: whenever you want to have more than one statement to be included under if, use `{}` blocks to wrap statements, else only first statement will bind to condition rest of will execute irrespective of condition

Comment: Who wrote this code and whom are they trying to punish?

Comment: Have you tried creating a test case with smaller overhead to better understand your problem?

Comment: @Biffen I am a beginner in Javascript and I wrote it

Comment: @plocks I am new to this, I don't understand what you are saying but I'll google it for a better understanding.

Comment: With `;` you have two separate statements which will both be executed. With `&&` whether the second expression will be executed depends on whether the first expression resulted in a truthy value or not.

Comment: A better way to approach your problem would be to use simplifications of your variables and look at their course through the code, while it executes. Try to Google for the "debugger;" statement in Javascript or use "console.log(var);" to output variable values at runtime.

Comment: @deceze So, when I use && operator and the first value turns out to be falsy, will it not move on to the second operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be better understood if I translate your code into a more readable code. See below.

Your code with `&&` is translated to this if your `if` statements are written with `{}`:

```js
var tipcalculator = {
  bills : [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
  tipmethod: function() {
    this.arraytip1 = [];
    this.arraytipbills = [];
    for (var i = this.bills.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      billsarr =  this.bills[i];

      if (billsarr > 200){
        this.arraytip1.push((billsarr*10/100))
        &&
        this.arraytipbills.push(((billsarr*(10/100)) + billsarr));
      }

      if (billsarr >= 50 && billsarr <= 200){
        this.arraytip1.push((billsarr*15/100))
        &&
        this.arraytipbills.push(((billsarr*15/100) + billsarr)); 
      }

      if(billsarr < 50){
        this.arraytip1.push((billsarr*20/100))
        &&
        this.arraytipbills.push(((billsarr*(20/100)) + billsarr)); 
      }
    }
  }
}

tipcalculator.tipmethod()
console.log(tipcalculator.arraytip1)
console.log(tipcalculator.arraytipbills)
```

This is your code with `;` when translated if your `if` statements are written with `{}`:

```js
var tipcalculator = {
  bills : [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
  tipmethod: function() {
    this.arraytip1 = [];
    this.arraytipbills = [];
    for (var i = this.bills.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      billsarr =  this.bills[i];
      
      if (billsarr > 200){
        this.arraytip1.push((billsarr*10/100));
      }
      this.arraytipbills.push(((billsarr*(10/100)) + billsarr));
      
      if (billsarr >= 50 && billsarr <= 200){
        this.arraytip1.push((billsarr*15/100));
      }
      this.arraytipbills.push(((billsarr*15/100) + billsarr)); 
      
      if(billsarr < 50){
        this.arraytip1.push((billsarr*20/100)); 
      }
      this.arraytipbills.push(((billsarr*(20/100)) + billsarr));
    }
  }
}

tipcalculator.tipmethod()
console.log(tipcalculator.arraytip1)
console.log(tipcalculator.arraytipbills)
```

Notice that the operations are completely different in all three `if` statements when you use different syntax (`&&` vs `;`).

**EDIT**

In case `&&` without `{}`, the `arraytipbills` is only run when the `if` condition is met.

In case `;` without `{}`, the `arraytipbills` is *always* run regardless of the condition because when `if` statements are written without `{}`, only the following *one* statement will be included in the conditional execution.

**PS**

Every `;` means the end of a statement.

So, if you use `;` you are separating statements.

If you use `&&` you are comparing/continuing statements.

Comment: When I use && operator and the first value turns out to be falsy, will it not move on to the second operation? Or will it execute both the operations regardless

Comment: @HarshShah with `.push` method the return value will never be falsy. The real problem is explained in the editted answer. Let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: Thank you. I understand it better now.

Answer (score 1):

A snippet

```
if (billsarr > 200)
    this.arraytip1.push((billsarr * 10 / 100)); this.arraytipbills.push(((billsarr * (10 / 100)) + billsarr));
```

actually means

```
if (billsarr > 200)
    this.arraytip1.push((billsarr * 10 / 100)); // this line is under the 'if' instruction

this.arraytipbills.push(((billsarr * (10 / 100)) + billsarr)); // this line will be executed always
```

See how the block of code inside your `for` loop is enclosed with curly braces `{ }`? It's exactly the same principle for `for` instruction as for `if` instruction.

Comment: Thank you. When I use && operator and the first value turns out to be falsy, will it not move on to the second operation? Or will it execute both the operations regardless

Comment: Generally, yes. But the first value in this specific case _won't_ turn falsy. The return value of `push` is the length of the array after the push, so at least 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use ; for ending the current statement, code written after ; will be executed outside the if condition . To use multiple lines inside if use {} curly brackets.

Comment: Thank you. When I use && operator and the first value turns out to be falsy, will it not move on to the second operation? Or will it execute both the operations regardless

Comment: If first value turns out be false, then it would not execute the second statement.But in you case first statement would never return false.